# Unexpected token function while creating component

Tags: angular, components

When I'am going to create a component in my angular project. 
`myProject/src/app/layout` in this path I want to create a new component. 
For that, I using this commnd.

`ng g c componentName`. I have create a few component by this way.

Currently, In my project, This is my project configuration.

`Angular CLI: 6.0.0
 Node: 6.11.1
 OS: win32 x64
 Angular: 6.0.9`

When I fire command I got this type of `error`.

`Error compiling schema, function code: var customRule0 = customRules[0];.......`

`Unexpected token function` **(In red font)**.

Comment: Consider updating (if you can without creating more problems) your CLI to 6.0.8 to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10850

Comment: @R.Richards I have upgrade my local angular cli to `6.0.8`. Still I got same error.

Comment: How about if you update node to version 8.11.3? I know that Node 8.9 is the minimum required according to the [prerequisites](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular/cli/README.md#prerequisites).

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Yes this is the same error I got. And finally I solved this by install update LTS node. I installed 8.11.3. And NPM 6.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just uninstall my node and install new node LTS version. I install `8.11.3` node version.